# TTF (truetype) to WOFF(webfont) conversion using ruby

Tags: fonts, font-face, truetype, webfonts, woff

How do you convert a .ttf file to .woff file (webfont) using ruby?

We want to allow users to upload a ttf file, convert it and embed the woff file.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but maybe you can check out how fontsquirrel does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two tools available to convert TTF to WOFF.

1. **sfnt2woff** - found here: http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/ - This is a command line tool that you should be able to call from Ruby
2. **sfntly** - found here: http://code.google.com/p/sfntly/ - This is a command-line Java suite developed by Google to do a bunch of font tasks, including WOFF generation.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that might be interested today, there is a small Ruby gem that I released today. It is using a Haskell binary that I tested on *Ubuntu 12TLS*, *Debian 7 Wheezy* and *Mac OSX 10.7.5*

https://github.com/dachi-gh/webify_ruby

You get `WebifyRuby` module by requiring `webify_ruby` and a `Convert` class on it which is used primarily.

```
require 'webify_ruby'
@convert = WebifyRuby::Convert.new(
  'public/fonts/my_font.ttf',
  dir:'my_dir_fonts/converted',
  css: 'my_dir_css/stylesheets',
  link_to: 'http://example.com/my_dir_fonts'
)
```

Only first parameter is required. without `link_to` for example, generated stylesheet's url's would be relative from .css file to webfont files.

*p.s. Currently it works good with `ttf` files but you can still use it with `otf`*